# How to get ubuntu to recognize a 4k monitor

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, 4k-monitor

I have an ASUS G501VW notebook and recently upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 (16.04 -> 16.10 -> 17.04) and the 4k monitor I am using via HDMI cable (Samsung 28" LU28E85KRS) is not showing resolution options beyond 1920x1080 anymore.

I tried updating the Intel Graphics Driver using the `intel-graphics-update-tool` and reinstalling the NVIDIA graphics driver, but none of those options solved my problem.

I tried setting a higher resolution using `xrandr` tool, but the screen blinks and displays an error message. It fails to set any resolution beyond 1920x1080.

Steps I did when using `xrandr` and the outputs:

```
$ cvt 3840 2160
# 3840x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 712.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 3840x2160_60.00

$ xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 3840x2160_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I am using Gnome.

**`xrandr` output:**

In this output you can see 2 monitors connected, but I also tried with only the 4K monitor connected (notebook screen disabled).

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.10 +  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 608mm x 345mm
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94*   30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   2560x1440_60.00  59.96  
   3840x2160_60.00  59.98  
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  2560x1440_60.00 (0x26a) 312.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.96Hz
  3840x2160_60.00 (0x273) 712.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4160 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock 134.18KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2237           clock  59.98Hz
```

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf:**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Anyone know what should I do to have the 2k and 4k resolutions working again?

**Edit**

I have done a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 and the problem persists when using HDMI, but I was able to get the monitor recognized as 4k by using an USB-C to MiniDP cable.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using the same screen with these steps:

Get the EDID information.

```
sudo apt install read-edid
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

Choose the preferred mode, in this case "Mode 0".

```
Modeline    "Mode 0" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync
```

Create the new mode.

```
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +
```

If you are not sure which one is the output, run `xrandr` and it will show something like `HDMI-2 connected`.

Use the name of the output.

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 3840x2160
```

Now the new resolution should be available in the Display settings.

Blog post about it: https://dobladov.github.io/blog/how-to-configure-a-4k-screen-in-linux/

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing you solution. Unfortunately, I can't test your solution now, because I don't have that monitor anymore.